# What is an infinite loop?

Tags: python

As far as I understand, when the condition-section of a loop doesn't have a terminating condition, that loop is called an infinite loop.

For example,

```
while True:
 text = input("Enter something (q to quit) # ")
 print(text)
 if text=="q":
   break
```

**Or**, if a loop never stops, that loop is called an infinite loop.

For example,

```
i = 0
while i == 0:
 text = input("Enter something (q to quit) # ")
 print(text)
```

**Am I correct?**

Comment: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/infinite
It doesn't have a particularly special meaning in a programming context, but an "infinite loop" usually indicates a programming error where a loop doesn't have a working terminating condition.

Comment: There are more than one type of infinite loop. Also, you can't always tell by inspection if a given loop is infinite in view of the unsolvability of the halting problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first example will never lead to an infinite loop occurring if the `input` function is behaving as defined, and if you have an input device connected to your computer such that you can cause that function to return a 'q'.  Your second example will always cause an infinite loop to occur when executed.

Technically speaking, there are never infinite loops IN your code. An infinite loop is something that occurs during your program's execution.  You can say you have an infinite loop when you know that the logic of the code given the current conditions means that there is no way to get a currently looping bit of code to exit that loop.  There are many things that can cause this.  Certainly, there are blocks of code that will obviously lead to an infinite loop occurring when that code is executed.

None of the three code snippets `while True: break`, `while True: pass` or `while True:` are infinite loops. They may or may not cause infinite loops when run. The presence of the line `while True:` does not mean you have code that will lead to an infinite loop. `while True: break` will never lead to an infinite loop when run. `while True: pass` will always cause an infinite loop when run.

Consider:

```
i = 1
while i != 0:
    i = someFunction()
```

There's no way to know if this will ever CAUSE an infinite loop or not.  It obviously will depend on if `someFunction` can ever be made to return `0`.  Maybe the function only returns `0` if the current date is in 1982.  If that's so, then it's an infinite loop.  But maybe it will return `0` two weeks from now.  In that case, it's not an infinite loop, but rather a loop that is not going to exit for two weeks.  Of course, these two examples assume that you don't go and change your computer's clock.  If you allow for that in asking if these are infinite loops, then the 1982 case is not strictly an infinite loop either if you can change your computer's clock and cause the function to return `0`.

With all of this said, I have no problem with someone labeling a piece of code as an infinite loop if it will pretty obviously lead to one occurring.  I'm not going to correct that individual. This is why I said "Technically" near the top of my answer.

Comment: I propose “trivially infinite loop”, for the 2nd case presented. Being the subset of infinite loops that are provably infinite (well, “infinite”) without much effort.

Comment: Makes perfect sense to me.

Comment: I would say that `while True` always sets up an infinite loop. `break` breaks you out of loops, including infinite loops. It *breaks* the loop. Just because a loop can be broken out of doesn't mean that the loop is not in and of itself an infinite loop.

Comment: @JohnColeman - I differ 100% with your definition of an infinite loop, obviously.  I use `while True:` all the time when I code, and there's nothing wrong with that.  To say that my code therefore contains lots of infinite loops is, in my opinion, silly.  Code is what it does.  The loop is the entire loop, not just the statement that initiates it.  A loop is categorized by its overall behavior.  Saying that a particular loop is an infinite loop that can actually be exited does nobody any good.

Comment: @Steve Good points. I have tended to think that when I write `while True:` I am writing a loop which in in some pedantic sense is an infinite loop, but a harmless one since I am able to kill it whenever I want to. Perhaps I read too much into the literal meaning of "break", thinking of it as something which simply destroys the loop rather than causing it to terminate regularly.

Answer (score 3):

You are correct on the part that if a loop doesn't have a terminating condition, it will not stop and will run infinitely. But your first example has a terminating condition when q is entered on input. So it isn't exactly an infinite loop.

Comment: What if a loop has a terminating condition that is never met? ie. Keyboard is unplugged? While this scenario seems silly, there are other cases (say, simple input exception violations) which might prevent a loop with a terminating condition from having the condition met.

Comment: In general, if the terminating condition is never reached the loop will run infinitely. In your example, if keyboard is unplugged your program will keep waiting for your input. That is not same as loop running infinitely. That is your program waiting infinitely. 

Comment: True, never-looping-loop ^_^

Comment: Your comparison of no user at the keyboard vs keyboard unplugged is an interesting one.  I'd say that given the current configuration of the hardware, one is an infinite loop and the other is not.  If you're allowed to plug the keyboard back in, and that will allow you to then exit the loop, then neither of them are infinite loops.

Answer (score 1):

I'm still a novice user (I've been learning C ++ for 2 months) but I would say the second definition is the correct one. Maybe I'm wrong and the two definitions are correct, correct me if that's the case.

Comment: The first one is not an infinite loop. There is a way to get out of it. The second one does not have a way to get out of it. So it will result in an infinite loop situation.